# celery routing - with priorities

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

Setup: celery 4.1, broker: RabbitMQ 3.6.5, backend Redis.

From the [Documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing), there are several ways for routing:

**[Option 1](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing) Automatic Routing:**

```
task_routes = {
        'import_feed_task': {
            'queue': 'feed_tasks',
            'routing_key': 'feed_tasks',
        },
}
```

**[Option 2](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#special-routing-options) Special Routing:**

```
task_queues = [
    Queue('feed_tasks', Exchange('feed_tasks'), routing_key='feed_tasks',
          queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 10},
]
```

I want to use the priority (`queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 10}`) within the first option. Is it possible/supported?

Comment: May I ask have you found a solution?

Comment: @GuohuaCheng I'm using the second option

Comment: Me too. Thank you!